# Chosen-ciphertext attack -- basic question

Tags: encryption, attacks, ciphers

Disclaimer: I'm a beginner with security.

Problem: I am reading Applied Cryptography by Schneier. He writes:

[image]

Question: How can "automatic decryption" work *without* the deduced key? Does the tamperproof box mean you can't access its private key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on @schroder's answer, the thought experiment that Schneier is building is similar to the [oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine)-based thought experiments that you see in other types of theoretical computing, and Schneier probably assumes that you are familiar with those types of proofs.

An *oracle* is usually some magic black box that is infinitely fast and knows everything that does some hard computation for you in zero time. You have no way to look inside it, but you can ask it as many questions as you like and see the corresponding output.

[image: input --> oracle --> output]

The general format of an oracle-based thought experiment is:

> Given access to an oracle which does *[computation X]* , does this make *[problem Y]* any easier?

Usually "any easier" is measured as "less time / less memory / fewer network packets / etc".

We could restate Schneier's definition as an oracle-based thought experiment by saying:

> **Chosen-Ciphertext Attack.** Given access to an oracle which takes the ciphertext `C` and produces the corresponding plaintext `P`, does this make the problem of deducing the decryption key any easier?

For some ciphers the answer is *yes* because you can deduce the key by sending some small number of carefully chosen ciphertexts to the oracle. We would say that this cipher is *vulnerable to a chosen-ciphertext attack*. For other ciphers the answer is *no* because the number of ciphertexts you would have to send to the oracle is similar to the number of guesses to brute-force the key, so the oracle is not actually saving you any time. We would say that this cipher is *resistant to a chosen-ciphertext attack*.

*Note that you usually see chosen-ciphertext attacks in academic papers used as a proof that some algorithm would make a good cipher, rather than as an actual attack that someone did in the real world.*

Answer (score 3):

The quote is simply setting up a thought experiment. The theoretical box in question just does decryption and has the key to decrypt, but the cryptanalyst cannot use weaknesses of the box to get a key.

The point of the example is simply that the cryptanalyst has access to the input and output, but not the process or key.

Comment: I think i misunderstood then because I was going to say work out the key using the encrypted and decrypted forms of the text xD ... clearly I misunderstood the point